# automatic .htacess file is creating. in public_html/wp-admin folder. how to stop

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

.htacess file have below code-

```html
<FilesMatch ".*\.(phtml|php)$"> Order Allow, Deny Deny from all </FilesMatch> <FilesMatch "(index).php$"> Order Allow,Deny Allow from all </FilesMatch>
```

This is blocking my admin panel. like page,post, appearance etc. when i am clicking on these section in dashboard not found 404 showing.

this .htacess file is continuous creating and i am deleting this file .htacess in admin folder then my dashboard are working. So please how to stop creating .htacess file in wp-admin folder.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all your plugin, and using a default theme?

Comment: yes, we are using different themes